# Generic mapping with Automapper

Tags: automapper, mappings

I would like to create a generic/common mapping that will be the equivalent of the following mappings but with single line.

```
cfg.CreateMap<int?, PropertyModel<int?>>().ConvertUsing<ValueToPropertyModelConverter<int?>>();

cfg.CreateMap<double?, PropertyModel<double?>>().ConvertUsing<ValueToPropertyModelConverter<double?>>();

cfg.CreateMap<string, PropertyModel<string>>().ConvertUsing<ValueToPropertyModelConverter<string>>();
```

I would imagine something like

```
cfg.CreateMap<TValue, PropertyModel<TValue>>().ConvertUsing<ValueToPropertyModelConverter<TValue>>();
```

Any ideas ?

Thanks !

Riana

Comment: http://automapperdocs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Open-Generics.html

Comment: Your link talks about mapping open generic type to another open generic type, that is not what the question was about ..

Comment: Nullable is a generic type.

Comment: Ok , but what about the last one with a string ?  Same question for non nullable types .. What I would like to achieve is to create just one map that can handle all these cases . Thx

Comment: That's more complicated. You can write a [simple custom object mapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=objectmapper&type=) to handle all cases. Or you let AM create the maps for you and then customize them with a type converter.

Comment: Ok, thanks Lucian I will take a look