# How can I use Automapper CreateMap in gerneric?

Tags: c#, generics, automapper, value-type

I have a generic object like this:

```cs
public class FieldOfT<TType>
{
    public TType Value { get; set; }
    public bool Foo { get; set; }
    public int Bar { get; set; }
}
```

I create a custom automapper type converter like this:

```cs
public class FieldOfTTypeConverter<TType, TFieldOfTType> : ITypeConverter<TType, TFieldOfTType> where TFieldOfTType: FieldOfT<TType>, new()
{
    public TFieldOfTType Convert(TType source, TFieldOfTType destination, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        if (destination == null)
        {
            destination = new TFieldOfTType();
        }
        destination.Value = source;
        return destination;
    }
}
```

At this point I need mappings from all ValueTypes (bool, char, double, etc) included their nullable types (bool?, char?, double?, etc).

The following code works fine:

```cs
this.CreateMap<bool, FieldOfT<bool>>().ConvertUsing<FieldOfTTypeConverter<bool, FieldOfT<bool>>>();
this.CreateMap<bool?, FieldOfT<bool?>>().ConvertUsing<FieldOfTTypeConverter<bool?, FieldOfT<bool?>>>();

this.CreateMap<double, FieldOfT<double>>().ConvertUsing<FieldOfTTypeConverter<double, FieldOfT<double>>>();
this.CreateMap<double?, FieldOfT<double?>>().ConvertUsing<FieldOfTTypeConverter<double?, FieldOfT<double?>>>();
```

Is there a more elegant solution? Like a list of types and a loop or a generic implementation?

This snipped as a rough idea:

```cs
this.CreateMap(typeof(ValueType),typeof(FieldOfT<>)).ConvertUsing(typeof(FieldOfTTypeConverter<,>));
```

Is it possible to collect all value types with `typeof(?)` ?

Comment: There is a closed issue (won't fix) about that: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/681.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49381319/generic-mapping-with-automapper?noredirect=1#comment85782577_49381319

Comment: Thank you, then there is really no better way. Then I do not need to brood.

Comment: That issue is too old to be relevant. That kind of mapping is possible but doesn't apply to your case. I've linked to how you could make it work.